# Office development with Visual Studio 2010 (VSTO), things to consider

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, ms-office

I'm still confused by the different versions of VSTO and in which way they are compatible to office 2007/2010. I know there is a [nice table for comparisons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) on wikipedia, but I still don't get it. My focus lies on PowerPoint.

Okay, so I have the Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition that provides two templates for PowerPoint: a 2007 Add-In template and a 2010 Add-In template. What exactly is the difference here, is it just the version of the underlying VSTO? Apart form that, is there a difference between VSTO 4.0 and VSTO 2010? Wikipedia uses both terms.

I want the Add-In to work with both PowerPoint 2007 and 2010. Should I chose the 2007 Add-in project type or the 2010 add-in project type?

Wikipedia says: *"Office 2007 applications can also use the VSTO 2010 runtime"* 
and it also says 
*"VSTO solutions developed against newer Office versions will not work in older Office versions as they lack the necessary Primary Interop Assemblies (PIAs)"*.

Isn't that some kind of contradiction?

Comment: I like Wikipedia too, but maybe you should ask Microsoft this question before asking Wikipedia? See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/threads.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I switched to msdn

Comment: Just read the table VSTO 4.0 is **Built into Visual Studio 2010 Professional and above** and VSTO 3.0 is **Built into Visual Studio 2008 Professional and above**  Office 2007 supoprts VSTO 3.0/4.0 Office 2010 only supports VSTO 4.0

Comment: my add in developed for Office 2007/VSTO 3.0 works on Office 2010 with VSTO3 and VSTO4 installed (surprisingly, both of them are required)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

below image should be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A VSTO project will work only with the selected version and later i.e. a 2007 add-in will work with Office 2007 and 2010, whereas a 2010 add-in will work with only 2010.

When deciding which version to choose for an add-in, choose the version of the oldest Office version you want to support.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's a bit more complicated than that.
Take a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb772080.aspx
It seems as long as I'm developing with .NET 4.0 it doesn't matter at all which versions and templates to chose, as long as I avoid features that are new in Office 2010.

Comment: +1 It's the safest way to go. But acually, I think that if one does not use any new features & API, and install VSTOR 4.0 on the client, Office 2010 Add-ins should also work in Office 2007. Justification: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx

Comment: There is a way to target 2007 and 2010 collectively using VSTO2010. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx